# Is it possible to make non-existing directories automatically when copying a file?

Tags: c++, c++17, std-filesystem

I'm experimenting with the new `std::filesystem` library.
I wish to make a program which copies files listed by the user into a given directory. But the naive approach using `std::filesystem::copy` or `std::filesystem::copy_file` didn't work when a listed file was in a subdirectory.

For example, suppose I want to copy some files in `(some directory)`, say

```
(some directory)/file1.ext
(some directory)/subdir/file2.ext
```

into `(some other directory)`, so that I get

```
(some other directory)/file1.ext
(some other directory)/subdir/file2.ext
```

The directory `(some directory)` may contain files or directories or etc. that need not be copied. If I use just `std::filesystem::copy`, then `file1.ext` succeeds but `files2.ext` fails when there is no `(some other directory)/subdir`.

The workaround was

1. Call `std::filesystem::path::remove_filename` to get the directory path.
2. Call `std::filesystem::create_directories` to make directories if they didn't exist.
3. Call `std::filesystem::copy` to copy the desired file.

I wonder if it is possible to make this 3-step-approach to just a one call. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::filesystem::copy("(some directory)", "(some other directory)", std::filesystem::copy_options::recursive);
```

Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_options

Comment: Sorry, but I mentioned "The directory (some directory) may contain files or directories or etc. that need not be copied"...

Comment: Sorry about that. I don't believe there is such a function. The linked source lists all of the options available to the copy function.